# Where can I obtain the web package

Tags: emacs, package, elisp, emacs24, package-managers

[paste-kde](https://github.com/diogofsr/paste-kde/blob/master/paste-kde.el#L7) requires the web package.

But that package is not in [ELPA](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/) ... where might I obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's this one:  https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-web

The [owner](https://github.com/diogofsr) of `paste-kde` has contributed to `emacs-web`.

Answer (score 2):

The most natural location to get it is [`melpa`](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) which is another source for `package.el`.

Comment: That's absolutely right; both [`paste-kde`](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/paste-kde) and [`web`](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/web) are there, with links to the corresponding github repositories.